# Can we use "to image" & "to imagine" interchangeably?

Tags: word-usage

Ok, see

> to image: form a mental picture or idea of. "*it is possible for us to
>   image a society in which no one committed crime*" [Source](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Aimage)
>
> to imagine: form a mental image or concept of. "*imagine a road trip
>   from Philadelphia to Chicago*" [Source](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20imagine)

So, my question is:

Can we use "*to image*" & "*to imagine*" interchangeably?

So that the 2 above sentences can be written as:

"*it is possible for us to image / imagine a society in which no one committed crime*"

"*imagine / image a road trip from Philadelphia to Chicago*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *feel* that "image" is very rare as a verb (and even rarer when you restrict its sense to what you gave above). Much rarer than "imagine."

But, given that "image" can also mean "to picture or represent in the mind; imagine; conceive," it seems it's synonymous with "imagine" and thus interchangeable. I guess this means all of your sentences are okay.

But I warn you that using "image" in this way sounds pretty strange/marked (at least to me)...

Comment: so you are native English speaker, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I am an American English speaker. I think most would agree with me that using "image" as a verb in this way is pretty RARE. Many might not even know that it can be used in this way. I wasn't sure about this use until this post!

Comment: I saw this question was asked in a Chinese yahoo-answers like website. The arguments were so much. Unexpected, it's so simple.